# Sample code for L298N H bridge Arduino Motor Driver not working

Tags: arduino, motor, h-bridge

I am quite new to robotics, arduinos, motors and that sort of thing so there is a very strong chance I am missing something very obvious. However, I have looked up multiple tutorials online, none using the exact same H Bridge as I am using.
I was wondering whether anybody has also uses the L298N H Bridge who could tell me why my code isn't working. ([Link to product I am using](https://www.altronics.com.au/p/z6343-l298-h-bridge-motor-shield/))

Code:

```
void setup(){
pinMode(13,1);
pinMode(12,1);
pinMode(11,1);
pinMode(8,1);
pinMode(10,1);
pinMode(9,1);
}

void loop(){
digitalWrite(13,1);
digitalWrite(12,0);
digitalWrite(11,1);
digitalWrite(8,0);
analogWrite(10,255);
  
  
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: if you seriously want help, then do not use descriptions, such as `code isn't working` ... it does not describe what is actually happening ... please describe what you expect to happen, and what actually happens ... also include information about the connections between the arduino and the motor driver

Comment: do not put info into comments ... add it to the question